# Unable to Connect Jenkins Windows 10 Slave to Master running

Tags: azure, jenkins, docker

My environment:

Master: 
Azure VM running Ubuntu 14.10
Docker (1.9) running Jenkins Image
I have added port 8080 (for UI) and 50000 (for slave) as endpoints on the Azure VM.

Slave: 
Windows 10 (running on Mac via BootCamp)
Configured the firewall to allow inbound and outbound traffic on port 50000 (that slave jnlp seems to be using).

I can access my Jenkins Master install over the web. I am trying to configure the slave on my Windows 10 m/c. I have tried all 3 methods to configure the slave.

Each time after several retries, the slave throws the "Connection Refused" error (screenshot attached).
[Slave Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAu0N.png)

Can someone help point me in the right direction? I have little knowledge of Linux systems but proficient with Windows.

I have tried the [workaround here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393711/jenkins-slave-cannot-connect-to-master) but it hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's three things that I think you can check here:

1. Check that you expose port 50000 on your Jenkins docker container. Check for the `Dockerfile`, there must be a clause `EXPOSE 5000` or something. Or when you run your container run it with something like this: `docker run -it -p 50000:50000` which maps local post 50000 to the containers port 50000.
2. Check that you don't have any security rules on Azure blocking port 50000 to your Azure VM. Don't know about Azure but in AWS you allow port 50000 in your security group(s).
3. Check your Azure VM's firewall. Is it Windows? Check the firewall and allow port 50000.  Is it Linux ?  Check iptables and allow port 50000.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Another thing you may want to consider, is whether you're experiencing a known bug in Jenkins.  For instance, [this one specifically](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22932), or any of these : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22Windows%22